# Displaying same page with different content based on database

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted some help in php.

I am making a website for a university in php which will have a information to be displayed for every teacher ,so the same page will be visible in different information depend on the login email !

right now, i have created my database and script of login ,but it's without session or cookies ,do i need those two to display a different information with mysql query thanks in advance!
----------login.php----------

```
   ?php
require_once('init.php');
include_once("scripts/connect.php");
$login_error = "";
$email = "";
$password= "";

if(isset($_GET['login'])){

    $email = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']));
    $password = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT mail_enseignant,Nom_Enseignant,Mot_de_passe FROM enseignant WHERE mail_enseignant='".$email."' AND Mot_de_passe='".$password."' LIMIT 1");
 echo mysql_error(); 
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1){
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
        $_SESSION['mail_enseignant'] = $row['mail_enseignant'];
        $_SESSION['Nom_Enseignant'] = $row['Nom_Enseignant'];
        $_SESSION['Mot_de_passe'] = $row['Mot_de_passe'];

        header("Location: note-on.php?email=$email");
        exit();
    }else{
        $login_error="invalid Information...";
    }
    }
?>
<h3>Ensiegnant Login Below</h3>
   <form action="?login" method="post" >
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enseingant Login</legend>

        <p>Mail_Ens: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" /></p>
        <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password;?>" /></p>
        <p>
            <?php if (isset($login_error) && ($login_error != "")){
                echo "<p style='margin-right: 10px;color: #ff0000'>".$login_error."</p>";
            }?>
        <input type="submit" value="Login Enseignant" name="submit_login"/></p>
      <!--  <input type="image" src="images/sign_in.gif" id="signin" alt="Sign In" />-->
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

and this is the page that i wanna desplay a diffrent informaition based on the email of teacher logged in with

--------note-on.php----------

```
   <div id="left_column">
      <div class="holder">
          <h2 class="title">Speciality & Groupe</h2>
        <ul class="nostart">
          <select name="select" class="textfields" id="Speciality">
            <option id="0">-- Select Speciality --</option>
            <?php echo $_SESSION['mail_enseignant']; ?> 
            <?php   
              if(isset($_GET['email'])){
                $getallSpeciality = mysql_query("select Nom_Specialite from specialite where enseignant.mail_enseignant='".$email."'and enseignant.Id_Enseignant=affecte.Id_Enseignant and affecte.Id_Groupe=groupe.Id_Groupe and specialite.Id_Specialite=groupe.Id_Specialite");
                while($viewallSpeciality = mysql_fetch_array($getallSpeciality)){
                ?>
                <option id="<?php echo $viewallSpeciality['Id_Specialite']; ?>">
                <?php echo $viewallSpeciality['Nom_specialite'] ?></option>
                <?php }} ?>
          </select>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: u can display different information without using session or cookies. But it will become complicated and when u r rendering to another pages its become difficult to handle. so its better to use sessions

Comment: ok ,i have edit my topic can u help me with that thanks !

Comment: Any answers here providing SQL inject-able code will be down-voted.

Comment: plz go through the below link it may help u http://www.sourcecodetuts.com/php/27/how-create-login-page-php-and-mysql-session

Comment: if the user's id is stored in the session at the time of login then u can fetch any data related to that user_id from any page.

Comment: what about my code i think it has a session ,No ?

Comment: sorry for this too many question ,can we talk about my code does my code stored in the session at the time of login ? and they are separate files login.php and note-on.php thanks

Comment: u can check whether session is set or not by trying to display session data means <?php echo $_SESSION['mail_enseignant']; ?>  before that u have to initialize the session ob_start();
session_start();

Comment: did u getting any error????????

Comment: i am getting this error when i tried to add the id_email :Error
SQL query:

ALTER TABLE  `enseignant` ADD  `Id_email` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT AFTER  `Mot_de_passe` ,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (  `Id_email` ) ;


MySQL said: Documentation

#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Answer (score 1):

**SESSION** and **COOKIES** are easiest way to it.
But if you don't want to want to use any of these the you can use **get** Method

```
http://mtsite.com?teacherid=somevalue
```

get this value

```
$id=$_GET['teacherid'];
```

and then process this id to get your desired output

Comment: so what's the variable that i have to put in the Get based on the code above thanks ?

Comment: "$id" is the variable

Comment: yes. In you case it will be email but it is suggested that you map your email to unique id in your table and then use that id to fetch data

Comment: in my data base the Id_enseignant is the primary key !

Comment: you can update you table by adding "email_id" field  **OR** you can create another table which will have fields "email_id int AUTO_INCREMENT" and "email varchar(100) UNIQUE" and then use this email_id

Comment: ok ,my database has a lot of tables and every table is related to another one ,do i really need to change it ,is there another way ,and please check my edit what did i do wrong ?

Comment: for your edit: you have not set the login field i.e. "$_GET['login']" is not set so your query won't be executed  **for table**                            if you don't want to create another table you can update your table with email_id field int it

Comment: if you wanna talk you can reach me on  [https://plus.google.com/+ashishmaurya945]

Comment: i don't know how to send u a msg ,but if u really wanna help me my friend send me a msg here best2gamer@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

well, just use an if condition:

```
<?php if($someConditionHere) : ?>
<div id="content1">
     <div>Content 1 Here</div>
</div>
<?php elseif ($otherConditionHere) : ?>
<div id="content2">
     <div>Content 2 Here</div>
</div>
<?php else : ?>
<div id="content3">
     <div>Content 3 Here</div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

or you could also use a switch case statement. Reference [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

### Edit

for using the $email from your example above modify the header like:

```
header("Location: note-on.php?email=$email");
```

and in note-on.php use:

```
<?php $email = $_GET['email']; ?>
<?php if($email == 'some@email.address') : ?>
<div id="content1">
     <div>Content 1 Here</div>
</div>
<?php elseif ($email == 'some.other@email.address') : ?>
<div id="content2">
     <div>Content 2 Here</div>
</div>
<?php else : ?>
<div id="content3">
     <div>Content 3 Here</div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

or use a switch statement

Comment: hey Guns thanks for the reply but i want to display information based on the user information email in my example how can i do that ?

Comment: thabks a lot for helping me ,but do i have to specify everytime the email ,how can i make it automatically ? should i do this : <?php if($email == 'email') : ?> ???

Comment: @user3566692, make a DB dip and save content to a database or save the information that changes to the database. That's how it is always done!

Comment: i am sorry ,i am newbie that's why i am asking thanks ,and i don't know what do u mean !

Comment: @user3566692, you are using `$_GET['login']` in note-on.php however, you are not passing *login* variable in `header("Location: note-on.php?email=$email");` which is why your query is not running

Comment: ahh , okay so the correct code is                                                                   <?php
      if(isset($_GET['email'])){